Equivalence between Hausdorff metric and Area metric using openness criterion
Prove that the Hausdorff metric and the Area metric are not equivalent on the set of all bonded polygons, but are equivalent on the set of all convex polygons. The area metric is defined as the symmetric difference of two sets A and B. AKA, $S(A)+S(B)-2S(A\cap B)$.
The textbook this problem is from does not describe converging sequences in different metrics before introducing this problem, so it would be more helpful to describe a proof using the openness criterion.
I’ve tried some of the following approaches:
Using a generalization of a ball in the area metric to find out if it’s also open in the Hausdorff metric.
Two metrics are equivalent if there are constants $c, C>0$ such that:
$C*d_{\delta}\ge d_{H} \ge c*d_{\delta}$ or where $d_{\delta}$ and $d_{H}$ are swapped. (I got pretty far in this approach with the latter inequality but realized that I had a poor definition of a ‘constant’)
Any help would be appreciated.
